# If a set is not $G_\delta$ in a metric space, is it also not $G_\delta$ is a larger metric space?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In particular I've proven that a set $S \subset [0,1]$ is not $G_\delta$ in $[0,1]$. In other words, it cannot be expressed as a countable intersection of open sets in $[0,1]$. It it also true that $S$ is not a $G_\delta$ set in $\mathbb{R}$? My intuition tells me that this is the case, but a rigorous argument escapes me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this reasoning is correct, and can be a bit more general.  Note that if $S \subseteq X$ is a G$_\delta$, we may write it as $\bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} U_i$ where each $U_i$ is open in $X$.  If $Y$ is any subspace of $X$, then $S \cap Y = \bigcap_{i \in \mathbb{N}} (U_i \cap Y)$, and each $U_i \cap Y$ is open in $Y$, meaning that $S \cap Y$ is a G$_\delta$ subset of $Y$.  You are interested in the case where $S \cap Y = S$, *i.e.*, $S \subseteq Y$.

Comment: Yes, of course! Sets open in $X$ stay open in $Y$. Thank you!

Comment: @Phonon: Well... sort of. Just a matter of being a bit more careful: The open sets in a subspace are exactly the intersection of open sets in the full space with the subspace itself.  (You're welcome, however.)

Comment: Yes, that's what I meant.